# how to bypass/avoid crsf on API post?

Tags: node.js, express

In a node application with ExpressJS we have CRSF middleware enabled.
This works great, however we have some routes starting with /api and accepting POST request which fail (forbidden) because there is no CRSF token of course.
How can we bypass/avoid CRSF for /api posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally pass inside of middleware, so one option is to look to a pattern like this:

```
function yourMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  if ( null !== req.path.match(/^\/api/) ) {
    next();
  }
  //your CRSF behavior here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I don't completely understand. Do you mean I have to add this in the express configuration before the if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
      app.use(express.csrf())

      app.use(function(req, res, next){
         console.log('req.url '+req.url);
        res.locals.csrf_token = req.csrfToken()
        next()
      })
    } or should they be combined?

Comment: The `csrf` behavior you're using runs on POST requests for all routes https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js To make this depend on the route, you'd implement the same behavior but `next()` whenever the route doesn't match one on which you'd like to add CSRF protection

Comment: If you want to use the same middleware, another option appears to be using a `GET` https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js#L70

Comment: Got it working thanks like this function apiMiddleWare(req, res, next) {
          if ( null !== req.path.match(/^\/api/) ) {
              next();
          }
          //your CRSF behavior here
          if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
              app.use(express.csrf())

              app.use(function(req, res, next){
                  console.log('req.url '+req.url);
                  res.locals.csrf_token = req.csrfToken()
                  next()
              })
          }
      }

Comment: Glad my answer could help! Anything I can do to nudge you toward marking it as correct?

Comment: Hello @buley, I get this error;
`Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'csrfToken'`
What should I do?

Comment: Express v4 doesn't bundle CSRF middleware anymore. Install https://github.com/expressjs/csurf instead

Answer (score 0):

What about registering those routes before the CSRF middleware? Like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your-secret'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use('/api', require('path to your module that does not need csrf'));
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use('/othermount', require('path to your module that needs csrf'));
```

Edit: Expanded code example to clarify what I was thinking.

Comment: How does one load middleware depending on the route? To my knowledge, you setup middleware on a server instance, before any routes callbacks or middleware are invoked.

Comment: Edited my example a bit. Im trying to make use of the fact that express (connect really) executes everything in order. So, if it finds a matching route before the middleware, that middleware is not used for the request.

Comment: Also using express 4 allows to build Router instances which will be good for this kind of problem.